# División en Java usando If y While

Tags: java, while, condiciones, division

Quiero insertar 2 números por consola para realizar una división y mostrar el resultado pero si el segundo numero (divisor) es 0, realizar un bucle hasta que sea distinto. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
public class Programa1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String primerDato;
        primerDato = br.readLine();
        float numeroUno =  Float.parseFloat(primerDato);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero");
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String segundoDato;
        segundoDato = br2.readLine();
        float numeroDos =  Float.parseFloat(segundoDato);
        float resultado;


        if (numeroDos != 0) {
            resultado=numeroUno/numeroDos;
            System.out.println("El resultado de dividir " + numeroUno +" con " +numeroDos +" es " + resultado);
        }
        else while (numeroDos !=0) {
            System.out.println("Vuelva a ingresar el segundo numero");
        }                  
    }
}
```

Funciona hasta que inserto 0, ahí el programa acaba y no es lo que quiero, sino que guarde el divisor cuando este no sea 0 y al fin realice la división. Perdón por la simpleza del problema para los expertos...

Comment: Buenas. Revisa siguiente condición: `if (numeroDos != 0)` si numero no es 0, despues `else while (numeroDos !=0) {
     System.out.println("Vuelva a ingresar el segundo numero");
    } ` esta parte nunca entrara porque es la misma condición que `if (numeroDos != 0)`. Tendrias que poner otra condición como `else while (numeroDos == 0)`, aqui si que entrara el bucle cuando sea 0 el numero introducido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal es analizarlo en cuanto ha sido introducido el número, por ejemplo:

```
public class Division {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
            num1 = sc.nextDouble();
        } while (num1 == 0);
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
            num2 = sc.nextDouble();
        } while (num2 == 0);
        System.out.println("El resultado es: " + num1 / num2);
    }
}
```

en este ejemplo se estan verificando los dos numeros que no sean 0 antes de realizar la operación

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionado